# SBS 2003 group policies

Tags: windows-sbs-2003

The SYSVOL folder has had the policies removing.

Anyone know how  I can have them recreated with there defaults and not losing the AD users etc.

All policies have been deleted and I found dcgpofix to recreate the default policy and default domain controller policy but nothing for the SBS ones.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Restore from backups.

Deleted files are deleted - sysvol is no exception.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have backups then you're pretty much out of luck.

You can migrate the GPO's (backup and import) from a working SBS installation to your installation, but it's not a trivial operation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys thanks. We have a shadow copy from a few days previous in a version of Veritas that is still running nightly.

We are going to attempt to restore from there.